# Fixed div on the bottom of the scrollable div

Tags: css

I need a create 4 cards with non-changable height with buttons on the bottom, but there are different text amount in each card.

Position Fixed is connected to body element,
position absolute scrolls with content,
position sticky appears when content ends.

https://codepen.io/anatoli101/pen/NVzbGY Here is a basic exemple of my problem

```
.content{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fixed-div{
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.button{
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get a much nicer result (no occluded scrollbars) using flex:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 400px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 250px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.fixed-div {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.button {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>I need grey area fixed on the bottom, not dependent on text amount</h1>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est ipsam quae optio! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque molestias natus officiis labore omnis corporis cupiditate quisquam nihil? Mollitia aperiam iusto iste minima ratione culpa veniam architecto facilis neque deleniti? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est ipsam quae optio! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque molestias natus officiis labore omnis corporis cupiditate quisquam nihil? Mollitia aperiam iusto iste minima ratione culpa veniam architecto facilis neque deleniti? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution produces the same effect with that styling (even better indeed because the scrollbar does not appear all the way), **but** if the grey `div` was not totally opaque or did not totally fill the space at the bottom of the container, you could see that the text is not actually going under it.

Comment: Your solution is more fragile because you have to ensure that height of bottom element always matches padding (not always possible when using mismatched units, text wraps across lines, symbols fonts in call-to-action buttons alter line height, etc.) No full-width bottom element is a deal-breaker, to me.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to achieve this is by wrapping the element with the class `fixed-div` inside a container, and moving the element with the class `button` outside of the element with the class `fixed-div`, so that it is the direct child of the container element. Then you can set `position: relative` to the container element, and `position: absolute` to the element with the class `button`. As the container element will have the exact same size (and especially the same height) as the element with the class `fixed-div`, the element with the class `button` will be positioned at its bottom.

You also will need to add a bottom padding to the element with the class `fixed-div` so that the button doesn't not hide its content, and so that it doesn't affect its defined height, you can set its `box-sizing` property to `border-box`.

See the following code:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>I need grey area fixed on the bottom, non depending of text amount  </h1>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est ipsam quae optio!loremLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque molestias natus officiis labore omnis corporis cupiditate quisquam nihil? Mollitia aperiam iusto iste minima ratione culpa veniam architecto facilis neque deleniti?Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis.Lore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est ipsam quae optio!loremLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque molestias natus officiis labore omnis corporis cupiditate quisquam nihil? Mollitia aperiam iusto iste minima ratione culpa veniam architecto facilis neque deleniti?Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis.Lore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-div">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores aspernatur error rem aliquam omnis eveniet consequuntur asperiores, aut explicabo eaque eos quos facere necessitatibus sit est ipsam quae optio!loremLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque molestias natus officiis labore omnis corporis cupiditate quisquam nihil? Mollitia aperiam iusto iste minima ratione culpa veniam architecto facilis neque deleniti?Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aut, eum, quia facere inventore perferendis aperiam recusandae nihil at aliquam ipsum excepturi eligendi animi, nam vel unde. Suscipit, tenetur veritatis.Lore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, quam. Hic unde nam dolor debitis voluptates officia earum, nostrum ut quae recusandae voluptate eveniet commodi ipsa dolorum nulla totam molestiae? </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I reduced the width of the text elements so that it works within a narrow container, you can run the code in full page if it is still too narrow.

---

Leaving the button inside the scrolling element and setting `position: relative` to the latter and `position: absolute` to the former wouldn't work as the bottom of the button would be positioned inside the scrolling element at `400px` which is the height of the scrolling element, and would scroll with its content.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Since '.fixed-div' is set with a fixed height of 400px and it is the immediate parent of '.button', there is no need of an additional container. You can add 'position: relative' to '.fixed-div'.

Comment: No, this won't work unfortunately. I edited my answer to explain why, and you can check what it would do here: https://codepen.io/augustedupin/pen/rgKjpy

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for the advanced description :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try code:

```
.fixed-div p{
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 350px;
}
```

This is a demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/zQaobq

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative;` for the parent (fixed-div) and `position:absolute;bottom:0;` for the child (button)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fixed-div{
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.button{
  position:relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```